# HTACCES rewrite rules without parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to make 301 redirection from my old url : www.test.com/?page=mypage&lang=mylanguage

to the new www.test.com/mylanguage/mypage

I was using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=mypage&user_lang=lang$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.joskin.com/lang/mypage [R=301,L,NE]
```

but when I click on my old link, it redirect me to http://test.joskin.com/lang/mypage?page=mypage&user_lang=lang

how can I take off these parameters from my new url ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close! Use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=mypage&lang=mylanguage$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.joskin.com/lang/mypage? [R=301,L,NE]
```

The change that I made here is to add an `?` on to the end of your rewritten URL. The `?` at the end of the redirected URL is there so that the query string does not appear on the end of the URL again.

I removed `^` from the query string, it is not needed.

I also updated the query to match the URL that you displayed at the top of your question. I will leave that to you if you wish to change it back.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.